# Series 2013 US dollar bills

Tags: currency, money, usa

it's 2015 now but still, I can't find any USD bills of 2013 series. All my bills are 2009 series (not even 2009A series). I'm looking for 100 dollar denomination. what's the latest series for USD bills?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems out of place at an Economics forum. 
This site gives you information about US paper currency releases:
http://www.uspapermoney.info/general/chron_s.html

Comment: yes, I know of that webpage, in fact that webpage is the reason I started paying attention to the series of my money. So I just made a withdrawal of 10K+ last friday and I specifically asked for the latest series. The teller gave me a bundle of squeaky clean, totally smooth (no wrinkle) sparkling of 100 bills. When I got home, I noticed the series were 2009 (Start with L), signed by Cabral, not Rios, hence the confusion. Thanks